# How to write a Unit test for inserting and retrieving an object to mongodb using mongoose, mocha and chai?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write a unit test for inserting (and then retrieving) a document to mongodb. However, I keep getting a timeout error, and it suggests that `done` is never called. (Mongod is running, and I can see the objects being inserted just fine as well as being retrieved, using console.log.)

What I'm using:

**Node.js,
ES6,
Mongoose,
Mocha,
Chai**

CheckbookEntry is a weird wrapper to some Mongoose calls that let's me work with promises.

```
    describe('create and getOneById', () => {
    it('creates a new checkbookEntry, and retrieves it from the db', (done) => {
        var EXAMPLE_ENTRY = {
            type: 'debit',
            date: Date(),
            description: 'Example of a cb entry',
            account: 'PNC',
            amount: 239.33
        };

        CheckbookEntry.create(EXAMPLE_ENTRY.type,
                              EXAMPLE_ENTRY.date,
                              EXAMPLE_ENTRY.description,
                              EXAMPLE_ENTRY.account,
                              EXAMPLE_ENTRY.amount)
                        .then(function(createdEntry){
                            return CheckbookEntry.getOneById(createdEntry._id);
                        })
                        .then(function(foundEntry){
                            expect(foundEntry).to.eql(EXAMPLE_ENTRY);
                            done();
                        }, function(err){
                            assert.fail(err);
                            done();
                        });
    }).timeout(5000);

}); // end describe create
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess, but I think that the problem may be caused by this:

```
.then(function(foundEntry){
    expect(foundEntry).to.eql(EXAMPLE_ENTRY);
    done();
}, function(err){
    assert.fail(err);
    done();
});
```

More specifically, using assertions in a fulfilled/rejection handler without continuing the promise chain.

If the assertion throws an exception, `done()` will never get called. And depending on which promise implementation is being used, you might never even get notified about the exception. Also, an exception thrown in the `onFulFilled` handler won't trigger the `onRejected` handler passed to the same `.then()` method.

Because Mocha [supports promises out of the box](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises), instead of using the `done` callback, return your promise chain:

```
return CheckbookEntry.create(...)
                     .then(...)
                     .then(..., ...);
```

That way, the exception will get propagated back to Mocha, which will handle it.

FWIW, Mongoose [also supports promises out of the box](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).